# Getiing a string of 0 characters from std input python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this URI problem https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1341
But I'm getting a 'ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack'. The problem input is:

First line: a int **t** (number of test cases)

First line of a test case: two ints **H** and **W** (1 ≤ **H**, **W** ≤ 20). Representing the dimension of the grid.

The next **H** lines contain the grid.

Next line: three ints **N** (0 ≤ **N** 500), **X** and **Y** (1 ≤ **X** ≤ **H**, 1 ≤ **Y** ≤ **W**)

The next line contains a string of **N** characters, N, E, W, S stands for North, West, South and East, respectively. The second kid's information follows, which is the same format.

Example Input:

```
1
3 4
ABCD
DEFG
ABCD
4 1 1
EEES
3 3 1
NES
```

The problem is that **N** can be 0. So I will have to read a string of 0 characters from input.

Example:

```
1
3 4
ABCD
DEFG
ABCD
0 1 1

3 3 1
NES
```

What I'm trying to do is:

```
t = int(input())
for x in range(n):
    H, W = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    grid = []
    for i in range(H):
        grid.append([])
        line = str(input())
        for j in range(W):
            grid[i].append(line[j])
    steps, xZero, yZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    directions = str(input()) # Here is the problem if steps == 0 I think
    # code for second kid
    steps, xZero, yZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    directions = str(input())
```

To me a 0 characters string is a blank line, on my IDE it works fine, but when I submit to URI I get an error.

Comment: which line throws that error?

Comment: on 3rd line 'H, W = [int(x) for x in input().split()]'

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, runs fine here: https://repl.it/Mbqp. btw should the first line define `n` (not `t`) as `n = int(input())`? otherwise on the second line `n` is undefined?

Comment: Welcome to http://stackoverflow.com: you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

There's a hundred ways to solve this. Here are three more common ones.

This example pads the list and then trims the beginning:

```
([int(x) for x in input().split()] + [0,0,0])[:4]
```

Breaking it down if your input is `1 2 3`, this will:

```
[int(x) for x in ['1', '2', '3']] -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ] + [ 0, 0, 0 ] -> [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0 ][:4] -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

If you input an empty string, however:

```
[int(x) for x in []] -> []
[] + [ 0, 0, 0 ] -> [ 0, 0, 0 ]
[ 0, 0, 0 ][:4] -> [ 0, 0, 0 ]
```

This example checks for len and pads the array if it is too short:

```
 input = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
 i_len = len(input)
 if i_len < 3:
     input += [0] * (i_len - 3)
 else:
     input = input[:4]
```

Breaking it down if your input is `1 2 3`, this will:

```
[int(x) for x in ['1', '2', '3']] -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ][:4] -> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

If you input a string w/ < 2 spaces, however, it will pad. With the input of `1`, it will:

```
i_len -> 1
input -> [ 1 ]
i_len < 3 => (i_len - 1 = 2) * [0] -> [0,0]
input = [ 1, 0, 0 ]
```

This one shortens that a bit:

```
input = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
i_len = len(input)
input += (3 - i_len) * [0]
```

This example uses try… except:

```
 try:
    steps, xZero, yZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
 except IndexError:
    steps, xZero, yZero = 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: the problem is not in 'steps, xZero, yZero = [int(x) for x in input().split()] ' because in the definition it is guaranteed that this line will contain 3 values. The problem is when steps = 0, so the next line is a string containing 0 characters, so when I do 'directions = str(input())' I think it's ignoring the blank line and getting the next one messing with the input order.

Comment: The same solution applies multiple ways.